# Getting [SYS/TEMP] Temporary system problem when importing to Gmail from Google Apps

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I have a Google Apps (for education) email address for work. I am leaving the job, and want to import all of my emails into my personal, regular Gmail account.

I attempted to use the tool called Mail Fetcher ("Check mail from other accounts using POP3"), as well as "Import Mail and Contacts". I followed the directions Google gives. However, it just generates an error.

Below is the error message I see when I try to use Mail Fetcher:

> Email address:    ln****@t****.org
>
> There was a problem connecting to
>   pop.gmail.com
>
> Show error details:
>     Server denied POP3 access for the given username and password.
>   Server returned error: "malformed command e127mb198161291itb"
>
> Username:
>
> Password: *******
>
> POP Server:     pop.gmail.com
>
> Port: 995

A different time, the error read as follows:

> Server returned error: "[SYS/TEMP] Temporary system problem. Please try again later. s82mb74850398ioe"

I have also received "The server has timed out" error. But I have tried this on several different days, and it still isn't working.

Could someone help me figure out how to import my mail?

---

Postscript: I successfully imported all of my mail into a different personal Gmail account. I still don't know why the first one didn't work.

Comment: Do you have POP3 access enabled in Gmail settings?

Comment: @Idisagree Of course. I already did all the things google said in their tutorial.

Comment: Please don't add the resolution to your question. Put it as a separate answer.

Comment: @AlE. That is not a resolution. The problem was not solved. The postscript is germane to the question.

Comment: So then you're still looking for a solution?

Comment: @AlE. In a practical sense, I am no longer looking for a solution. But the question is still unsolved, and of general interest to a thousand other viewers.

Answer (score 4):

For error message

> Server denied POP3 access for the given username and password.

From: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/gmail/ntU1MOPy6aI/z-gLJ6B9HUoJ

> clear the captcha  see below
>
> Please try this
>
> 1. Open an incognito window.
> 2. Copy and paste this link: https://www.google.com/accounts/UnlockCaptcha.
> 3. Sign in to your gmail account
> 4. Complete CAPTCHA.

Answer (score 2):

For the error:

> Server returned error: "[SYS/TEMP] Temporary system problem. Please try again later. s82mb74850398ioe"

I found the username for the server settings wasn't using the full email address only the prefix. Adding the @everything else seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From: [Check emails from other accounts using Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/21289?hl=en)

> ## First, change your settings in your other account:
>
> 1. Open the Gmail account you want to import from.
> 2. Click the gear in the top right.
> 3. Select **Settings**.
> 4. Select the **Forwarding and POP/IMAP tab**.
> 5. Forwarding, POP & IMAP tab
> 6. In the “POP Download” section, select **Enable POP for all mail**.
> 7. In the drop-down menu next to “2. When messages are accessed with POP,” choose what to do with messages in this account, such as **keep**
>      **Gmail’s copy in the inbox** (recommended).
> 8. Click **Save Changes** at the bottom of the page.
>
> ## Then, change your settings in your new account:
>
> 1. Open the Gmail account you want to import to.
> 2. Click the gear in the top right.
> 3. Select **Settings**.
> 4. Select the **Accounts and Import** tab.
> 5. In the **Check mail from other accounts (using POP3)** section, click **Add a POP3 mail account you own**.
> 6. Enter the full email address of the other account, then click **Next Step**.
> 7. Enter your password. If you use 2-Step Verification, you’ll need to enter a new [app password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en).
> 8. Now you have a few options to choose from. Here’s our recommended settings:
>
>    - **Leave a copy of retrieved messages on the server** - Leave unchecked. This setting is controlled in the POP settings of your other account.
>    - **Always use a secure connection (SSL) when retrieving mail** - Keep checked.
>    - **Label incoming messages** - Check the box if you’d like to easily see which emails in your inbox came from this account.
>    - **Archive incoming messages** - Leave unchecked. Only check if you don’t want to see new messages from the other account in your inbox.
> 9. Click **Add Account**. If you get an error message while getting set up, click the **Show error details** link to find out more about what’s
>      not working.
> 10. Once your account has been added successfully, you'll be asked if you want to be able to [send mail as this address](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en). This lets you
>       compose messages in Gmail, but have them appear to be sent from your
>       other email account.
>
> Gmail will check your other account for new emails periodically. You
>   can see when the other account was last checked from the [Accounts and
>   Import](https://mail.google.com/mail/#settings/accounts) tab in Settings.
>
> **If you only want to import old emails**, you can stop importing mail
>   after your old messages have been imported.

Comment: Thanks - I did that all already and received the error message in my question.

Comment: From step 9.  "If you get an error message while getting set up, click the Show error details link to find out more about what’s not working". Did you click the link? What say the linked page?

Comment: The error: Server returned error: "malformed command e127mb198161291itb"